# Android BadgeView no show in Fragment onStart

Tags: android, android-fragments

I used the BadgeView and want to show badge number when Fragment Tab OnStart.
BadgeView was successfully show in FragmentActivity class, but somehow it doesn't show in
Fragment class.
Please help me...
here is my code

```
enter code here
```

public class Info extends Fragment {

```
@Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
  }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_info, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

    TabWidget tabs = (TabWidget) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),tabs,2);
    badge.setText("8");
    badge.show();       


}
```

}

Comment: try this `TabWidget tabs = (TabWidget) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);`

Comment: Wow,Yes!!!!!It's work!! Dear Simple Plan, thanks a lot..you save me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this

```
 TabWidget tabs = (TabWidget) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
```

to

```
 TabWidget tabs = (TabWidget) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
```

Comment: its not worked in my case , in my mainactivity,i have  created my Tabs (im using tabLayot for tabs) and when i try this method in fragment , it is not giving any kind of error but badge didt show up. i dont know wht is the problm. plz help